# .NET6: Disable bundling during debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .NET6 project I create during startup a bundle using `pipeline.AddCssBundle("~/BundleName", "file1", "file2")`. In my view I include it via:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/BundleName" asp-append-version="true" />
```

The problem with this: Visual Studio's Hot Reload feature does not work because the bundle is generated during startup and won't change when its content files change. So I need to disable bundling during debugging.

Ideally, I want to create my own `<link>` tag helper and use it like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/BundleName" disable-bundling-during-debug="true" />
```

For this, I need to access the bundle in my tag helper and obtain the individual files ("file1" and "file2" in my sample above). So I can create one `<link>` element for each of them.

Any thought how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing the question I came up with this solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension of AspNetCore LinkTagHelper which allows disabling bundling and caching
/// </summary>
public class LinkTagHelper : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.LinkTagHelper
{
    private readonly IAssetPipeline mPipeline;
    public bool DisableBundlingDuringDebugging { get; set; }
    public bool DisableCaching { get; set; }

    public LinkTagHelper(
        IAssetPipeline pipeline,
        IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        TagHelperMemoryCacheProvider cacheProvider,
        IFileVersionProvider fileVersionProvider,
        HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder,
        JavaScriptEncoder javaScriptEncoder,
        IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory) : base(hostingEnvironment, cacheProvider, fileVersionProvider, htmlEncoder, javaScriptEncoder, urlHelperFactory)
    {
        mPipeline = pipeline;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (output == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output)); }

        var isBundle = mPipeline.TryGetAssetFromRoute(Href, out var bundle);

        if (!DisableBundlingDuringDebugging || !isBundle)
        {
            // Use AspNetCore Tag helper
            base.Process(context, output);
            return;
        }

        // Custom implementation which disables bundling
        var suffix = DisableCaching ? "?t=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks : string.Empty;
        var itemCount = 0;
        foreach (var bundleItem in bundle.SourceFiles)
        {
            itemCount++;
            if (itemCount == 1)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", bundleItem + suffix);
            }
            else
            {
                output.PostElement.AppendHtml($"<link type=\"text/css\" ref=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{bundleItem + suffix}\" />");
            }
        }
    }
}
```